# Is it possible to localize Facebook login permissions message?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-login, facebook-sdk-3.0

In my app I use Facebook login for my users for authentication. However, when they log in and they are prompted with the permissions I require, Facebook displays a dialog with a mix of English and German (since my app is German).

Is it possible to set a language flag or something similar, so that I can tell Facebook "Ok, only use English" or "Please please use only German words".

Technically, I simply use the LoginButton from the Facebook SDK 3.6, which just opens the Facebook LoginActivity (which should handle the authentication stuff).

Answer (score 1):

Facebook library use 2 ways to get messages. There is the library values (you can find it in /myfacebooklibrary/res/values/strings.xml for default and /myfacebooklibrary/res/values-es/strings.xml for spanish for example). If there is not germany locale in your library you can just create one.

But there is messages from facebook server, like the permissions requests. This messages you can configure in facebook [App Dashboard](https://developers.facebook.com/apps). But I don't know if you can force use some locale, I guess facebook use the default locale of user.

Answer (score 0):

Need to write meta-data (in AndroidManifest.xml) android:value is unicode.
if facebook_app_id is '1234', in AndroidManifest.xml

```
  <meta-data
    android:name="com.facebook.sdk.ApplicationId"
    android:value="\u0031\u0032\u0033\u0034" />
```